# Bibtex errors-Top level auxiliary file

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to get references with TeXstudio. I followed exactly [an online tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NRXvqthfDG0&index=3&list=PLMgDLOeiDWEwYC2kVQ-ztFHtPX47nmt0h), but I have the following problem when compiling BibTeX:

```
Process started: bibtex.exe "Κύριο μέρος"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file:

Process exited with error(s)
```

I would be grateful if someone tell me what to do. I am trying this for hours...

I renamed my file and now the following errors appear

```
Process started: bibtex.exe "main"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: quote.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: ch1.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: ch2.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: ch3.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: ch4.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: ch5.aux
The style file: plain.bst
White space in argument---line 40 of file main.aux
 : \bibdata{\LGR\textBeta
 :                        \LGR\textiota \LGR\textbeta \LGR\textlambda \LGR\textiota \LGR\textomicron \LGR\textgamma \LGR\textrho \LGR\textalpha \LGR\textphi Ð\LGR\textalpha }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file main.aux
(There were 2 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

My TeX code is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%-----------------------
\usepackage{graphicx}
%------------------------
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

%--------------------------
\usepackage{setspace}
%--------------------------
\usepackage[width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

%----------------------------
%-------------------------
\pagestyle{headings}



%------------------------------
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%-------------------------------
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}
%----------------------------
\usepackage{kmath,kerkis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{upgreek}

%-----------------------
\newcommand{\la}{\latintext}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}
\newcommand{\lat}{\latintext}
%------------------------
\usepackage{syntonly}
%\syntaxonly
%-----------------------
\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{thm}{Θεώρημα}[section] % reset theorem numbering for each chapter
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Ορισμός} % definition numbers are dependent on theorem numbers
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Παράδειγμα} % same for example numbers
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Πόρισμα}

%--------------------
\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
%------------------
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
%---------------------------------
\usepackage[pdftex,pdfnewwindow=true,colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=red,
urlcolor=cyan,
citecolor=green]{hyperref}
%\includeonly{ch1}
%------------------------------------------------------------
%------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\input{titlepage}


\include{quote}


\tableofcontents

\input{ch0}

\include{ch1}

\include{ch2}

\include{ch3}

\include{ch4}

\include{ch5}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Βιβλιογραφία}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Rename your file and use only a-Z and no spaces.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I renamed my file and now the following errors appear

Comment: You only renamed the main file, your bib-file still uses non-ascii chars.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer i renamed the bib file as bibfile.bib now i am getting the following warning :Could not start Default compiler:PdfLatex:pdflatex.exe-synctex=1-interaction=nonstopmode "bibfile".tex

Comment: Make sure that your tex file is really the master/main file. Perhaps restart the editor, or compile at first on the command line.

Comment: @Fisher thanks a lot .Now i have a different problem.The references are in english but i am getting greek ( i am writing in greek ) .An example is @book{thenot,
 language = {english},
 author = {Tobias Oetiker and Hubert Partl and Irene Hyna and Elisabeth
 Schlegl},
 title = {The Not So Short Introduction to LATEX 2" Or LATEX2e in 157
 minutes},
 year = {2011},
 url= {http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf}
}

Comment: i am getting usually warnings like this:Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textrho' .what is the problem?Is it the font ?

Comment: You should make a example that **others** can compile and that demonstrates your problem. Remove all the input and include, and show your bib-entries. Don't add code in the comments, edit your question instead. And don't add new questions in comments. Create a real new independant question when you get  a new problem. And my name has "c" in it.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I am sorry. I 'll try again.